# Anonymous functions are not supported for code generation Matlab 2015b

Tags: matlab, simulink, anonymous-function

I have a strange problem. I have an .slx model which I developed in SIMULINK on Matlab 2017a. It is working fine and there is no problem.

I exported it, through *' Export Model To -> Previous Version '* utility of Simulink and the export went smoothly.

I now opened MATLAB 2015b and I tried to build the model created but it tells me:

*Anonymous functions are not supported for code generation.*

Did something changed about the supported stuff for code generation between versions 2015b and 2017a?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for anonymous functions was introduced in R2016b.  See the MATLAB Function section of the R2016b [Release Notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/release-notes.html) for more information.